# Problems with AVX computations: can I run avx2 codes?

Tags: c++, assembly, sse, avx, avx2

I've been using Intel's SSE instructions with good performance gains and, recently, I tried to use AVX instructions.

The problem is: I can compile my avx instructions, but I cannot run them. The instructions are:

```
__m256i* avx1 = (__m256i*)vct1;
__m256i* avx2 = (__m256i*)vct2;
__m256i* avx3 = (__m256i*)vct3;

__m256i va0, va1, va2;            

va2 = _mm256_and_si256(va0, va1);
```

The only way I can compile these instructions is by having -mavx2 flag. Without this flag I can't compile the code and I received this error:

```
"sseAND.cpp:124:33: error: ‘_mm256_and_si256’ was not declared in this scope
  va2 = _mm256_and_si256(va0, va1); 
"
```

Ok, after compilling with -mavx2 and running the code, I received this error messagem:

`"Illegal Instruction`".

Running `/proc/cpuinfo`, I saw my Sandy Bridge CPU has support only for AVX instructions, not AVX2.

The question Is: is there anything wrong with my code or with my gcc flags?

Can I run the avx instructions I put below in my Sandybridge?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `_mm256_and_si256` is an AVX2 instruction. Sandy Bridge only has AVX.

Comment: Oh and if you weren't aware of it already, AVX has 256-bit instructions for floating-point, but not for integer. So if you want 256-bit integer instructions, you need AVX2 - which your processor does not have.

Comment: Thank you! This is new to me. I thought AVX had support for int and double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sandy Bridge only has AVX support. You're out of luck there unless you buy a Haswell CPU.

[Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) has support for AVX2 emulation since [v2.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bochs/files/bochs/2.5/), but it will be much slower, you only can test the correctness of your code.

Comment: Bochs looks really cool!  VirtualBox does not even support AVX even on a system that has AVX.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about Bochs. I will try it.

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to mark this question as answered.